# Propel as a Standalone Library

Tags: php, doctrine, pear, propel

I want to use Propel as a Standalone Library just as Qcodo or Doctrine e.g. without using Pear or Phing. I want to run both the generator and runtime in a Phing Free and Pear Free Environment. Is that Possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is planned that Propel **generator** runs without Phing for version 1.6 (http://www.propelorm.org/ticket/855)

AFAIK Propel **runtime** doesn't require Phing and can be embedded in any application.

Answer (score 0):

You can [download propel](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Download) in a tarball, or get it through checkout from the subversion repository, or PEAR. :)

**Edit**: Of course you will still need phing to use propel, as it [lists phing as a hard dependency](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Introduction/Requirements) for the generator.

Maybe you can comment as of why you don't want phing or which problem you encountered when you tried to install it?

Comment: This requires you to Have Phing !!

Comment: I extended my answer. It's a hard dependency for the generator. Do you want to comment why you can't use it?

Comment: Phing doesn't need to be installed via PEAR in order to work. Just make sure the Phing folder is added to the include paths (/path/to/phing-2.4/classes).